Error: querySrv EDESTRUCTION _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.t5yysak.mongodb.net
My Express app is working fine but I am unable to access the mongodb database, through Mongodb Compass. It throws the following error ->
querySrv EDESTRUCTION _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.t5yysak.mongodb.net
I donno how to solve it, the connection string is correct, and the network access is set to 0.0.0.0/0 It was working fine last time I accessed it. And it is working fine when I access it through the browser. Only Compass is throwing the error.
I tried resetting the network access, restarted the app, but nothing works. I want to get access to my database through compass.

I suggest to contact the MongoDB support.

I searched on their discussion forum and found nothing.

I didn't write their forum. Contact the support, most likely you pay for it. Open a ticket at https://jira.mongodb.org/issues/

That looks like a nodejs-specific DNS error: dns.DESTRUCTION: Channel is being destroyed from https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html

Did you manage to solve this issue?

No, I did not able to solve this issue. Its still persisting in my MONGODB COMPASS
